# Cubes covering a set in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let's say I divided $\mathbb{R^3}$ with 3 mutually orthogonal systems of planes and the distance between two neighboring planes of each system is $\varepsilon$. So basically what I have is countable amount of cubes covering $\mathbb{R^3}$ with an edge length of $\varepsilon$. I will label each cube somehow, for example $\mathcal{C}_{\varepsilon}^{k}, k\in\mathbb{N}$ .

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^3}$ be an arbitrary measurable set and $\tilde{\Omega}=\{\mathcal{C}_{\varepsilon}^{k}|\mathcal{C}_{\varepsilon}^{k}\cap\Omega\neq\emptyset\}$. What is the ratio
$$
\alpha(\varepsilon)=\frac{|\tilde{\Omega}|}{|\Omega|},
$$
where $|\bullet|$ is the Lebesgue measure and $|\Omega|\neq0$ ? Can I determine such thing somehow?

Comment: How do you define $|\Omega|$?

Comment: It is the Lebesgue measure, so $\Omega$ is also measurable. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: We can simplify $\alpha(\epsilon)$ to be $\frac{N\epsilon^{3}}{|\Omega|}$ where $N$ is the number of cubes that intersect $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, but $N=N(\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio can be arbitrarily large. Take a ball around a point of radius $\delta << \epsilon$. Then the ball has measure that is (up to a constant) $\delta ^2$, and even as we let $\delta \to 0$ this ball will be contained inside at least one cube, and $\epsilon^3 / \delta^2 \to \infty$ as $\delta \to 0$.

Comment: But I don't want to change $\Omega$, this set is fixed.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know what $\Omega$ is. So you can't bound the ratio, because for any bound I can find an $\Omega$ small enough where this bound fails.

Comment: To put that another way, if you want to estimate the ratio without giving more information about $\Omega$, then your estimation needs to work for all $\Omega$ at once.